# grouping together issue in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the total number of stores that have received two particular items.

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(stores_i), item_i
FROM all_stores  
WHERE item_i in (101, 105)
AND date_available IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY store_i, item_i
;
```

When I run this it gives me every store (1,2,3,4...etc) from the store column, 
It also gives me a one beside every store for item_i table. 
However I want it to just have a number that states how many store received item 101 and item 105.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT store_id
      FROM all_stores  
      WHERE item_i in (101, 105) AND date_available IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY store_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 2
     ) a;
```

The subquery gets the stores that sell both items.  The outer query counts the number.